# Does options exercise increase a stock's trading volume?

Tags: stocks, options, option-exercise, trading-volume

When I buy or sell a stock, the transaction will increase the stock's trading volume. Instead, suppose I buy an option and decide to exercise it immediately (for whatever reason). When I exercise a call option, I am *buying* stock from the counterparty. When I exercise a put option, I am *selling* stock to the counterparty. Does options exercise increase a stock's trading volume?

Comment: Anything that involves people having to buy and sell stock will impact the volume of that stock, so yes.

Comment: @Philip So if I exercise an options contract, 100 shares get added to the stock's trading volume?

Comment: Yes, as to deliver the stock to be delivered you have to purchase it (note it can be pre owned, so doesn't have to hit volume that day, but at some point it has to hit the volume)

Comment: Nope, they do not. Option delivery is not a trading activity. What if the seller hands shares out of his portfolio? What price would you report them - the option may be DEEP in the money.

Comment: See above as I specifically mention pre owned shares.

Comment: If it is not a pre owned share the answer is still no because it is NOT the exercise that is triggering the volume, it is offsetting buy order. Yes, ANAL - but exact definitions matter and knowing exactly what happens makes often the difference between asking here or - making money.

Comment: Philip - `note it can be pre owned, so doesn't have to hit volume that day, but at some point it has to hit the volume`.  It would have hit the volume some day anyway if the stock was was pre owned.  What happens some day has nothing to do with the question of: `Does options exercise increase a stock's trading volume?`

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no. It all depends on whether the stocks you get are bought by the seller or whether he transfers you stock from his portfolio (i.e. I am long, sell you a call, then give you my shares). In the last case there is no transaction happening that hits the trading volume.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer has been downvoted. The downvoters did not leave any comments. Did they think that your answer is incorrect? Your explanation makes sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

If satisfying the assignment/exercise of the contract results in transfer of shares to the counterparty, there is no stock exchange transaction since the trade occurs at the strike price between the two counterparties.

If one of the parties needs to acquire the shares in order to deliver or if one of the parties chooses to close the assigned shares then a transaction will occur on the stock exchange.